# Addressing two people in one mail

Tags: forms-of-address

I would like to address a mail to two persons not in a strictly professional manner, something like 'Hi Ann/Jack' is this the correct way of mentioning?

Also is use of a slash considered professional?

Comment: It's not categorically unprofessional, but the effect of the slash is usually that of _combination_ and while most people would interpret it as a perfectly normal way of combining two people into the target of one hello, the people involved might feel as though their individualities are threatened. Better to write more like you would talk, especially if you aren't in a formal situation. Something like “Hi Ann, hi Jack” ought to do nicely.

Comment: As a side note, the correct plural form of *person* is *people*, not *persons*.

Comment: I faced a similar issue, to write the same email to seven people, and I used "Dear friends”

Comment: @LucianSava I find it odd to start an email with 'Dear...', which to me is a salutation to be reserved for letters. "Hi all" is what I write in emails to multiple addressees.

Comment: This is more a question of etiquette than language rules. Maybe better suited to http://http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could say something like "Ann/Jack, could I have a status update on X?" It would probably mean you didn't know which of them was working on X.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Work (workplace).

Answer (score 5):

It should be fine. I would avoid using 'Hi Ann, Hi Jack', and use either 'Hi Ann/Jack' or 'Hi Ann and Jack' or 'Hi all'. I would also avoid using 'Hi friends', it is not normally used in English speaking countries by anyone other than language learners!